# Detect BLAS/LAPACK vendors using CMake

Tags: cmake, lapack, blas

So my code wants to include different header files when occurs to different BLAS/LAPACK vendors. Are there any predefined macros or something like that make me check it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMake 2.8+ ships with FindBLAS.cmake FindLAPACK.cmake.  You may want to review the comments in the files from your local cmake install: cmake-2.8.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake.  This module supports a variety of BLAS and LAPACK implementations.  For example:

```
set( ENV{BLA_VENDOR} "ATLAS" )
find_package( BLAS REQUIRED )
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

(this is an answer for the CMake 3.x era)

I used to do a complicated workflow similar to the other answer, in which I tried with different explicit vendors to detect the BLAS distribution.

The problem with that is that you have to try many possibilities and the logic becomes complicated.
Also you are overriding the vendor choice if this was made from the command line.

So, what I do now is to inspect the output variables and set variables or take any specific action:

```
find_package(BLAS)
if(BLAS_FOUND)
    message("Some BLAS found: linker flags ${BLAS_LINKER_FLAGS}, libs ${BLAS_LIBRARIES}, libs95 ${BLAS95_LIBRARIES}")
    foreach(lib ${BLAS_LIBRARIES})
        if(${lib} MATCHES "mkl")
            message("Some BLAS found matches MKL")
            add_definitions(-DBLAS_DOT_RETURNS_VOID)
            # in some systems with MKL, regular BLAS headers need to be found for it to work
            SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
            SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)
            SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib64")
            SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
            SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib64")
        endif()
        if(${lib} MATCHES "hpc_sdk")
            message("Some BLAS found matches hpc_sdk (nvhpc)")
            add_definitions(-DBLAS_DOT_RETURNS_VOID)
        endif()
        ... do this for Apple Accelerate, ATLAS, etc
    endforeach()
endif()
```